# OpenVPN one account multiple servers & Load Balancing

Tags: network, linux, vpn, ubuntu, openvpn

I have recently been experimenting with OpenVPN. My aim is to create a group of servers in different locations with a single username and password for each user stored in a central database. For example:

- LOCATION1.ovpn
- LOCATION2.ovpn
- LOCATION3.ovpn
- LOCATION4.ovpn
- LOCATION5.ovpn

So a user can choose a location from the above list of ovpn files and login with a single username and password (e.g. `username: dave` and `password: pass123` will work across all servers). Let's say the user selects `LOCATION1.ovpn` the system will then choose between 4 servers at that location depending on current connections (loadbalancing) and to also act as failover. I have done some research and seen from the [OpenVPN documentation](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#loadbalance) that this could be configured using the following approach:

```
remote server1.mydomain.example
remote server2.mydomain.example
remote server3.mydomain.example
```

I have successfully installed and configured all 20 servers. However, I am having issues getting the above configuration to work especially allowing users to authenticate with any of my servers with a single user and password set from a central point.

Comment: Might be something to do with certificates, look into that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to build your internal PKI first, then do IP/routing/user data replication on all your OVPN servers as you wish.

Pritunl has just solved these problem with mongodb, you might take a look and maybe follow this approach to replace with mysql/glusterfs ... whatever.